# Domain Driven Design - Entities

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

Based on my reading, I understand that entities are more than just models.  They represent a domain object and so contain properties, but also can include business logic.

In my case, let's say I have a notion of a "licensedUser" in my domain.

A licensed user can have the following properties (which are all currently a part of the LicensedUser.cs class:

```
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime? MembershipDate { get; set; }
```

But ... what about the logic that retrieves this entity from the database?  can i create a method like:

```
  public LicensedUser GetUser(string id)
  {
        var user = userRepository.GetUser(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            Log.Error("[{user}] could not be found", id);
            throw new ArgumentException($"User '{id}' could not be found");
        }

        return user;
    }
```

Does it belong here?  Sorry it might be a remedial question but just want to be sure I have the right paradigm in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the logic to retrieve an Aggregate Root is in a Repository, so what you have in there looks ok. The method `GetUser` could be in an Application Service (for example if you have an web API to retrieve the LicensedUser Aggregate the flow would be: Controller -> Application Service -> Repository).

A clarification: entities are only loaded as part of their root aggregate and shouldn't leak outside (as in something external of the aggregate calling methods on an entity to change its state). A DDD Entity is an implementation detail of the aggregate.

And another clarification. The idea of objects having data and behaviour (including business logic) is a basic tenet of object orientated design, it has nothing to do with DDD. Unfortunately, most 'OO' code is designed using procedural approach that resembles Cobol 60 (and I'm not being fair to Cobol).